# Get the type of the constructor function of the algebraic data type

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to get the type of the constructor function of the algebraic data type?

If I have a data like:

```
data UserDefinitionData = Foo | Bar Int | Baz String String | Hoge {abc :: String}
```

I want to get something like:

```
[[], [Int], [String, String], [String]]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

---

For your reference, I can get constructor names and field labels by [Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Data.html).
However, I don't know whether I can get info of arguments from `Constr`.

```
>> show $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ Foo
[Foo,Bar,Baz,Hoge]
>> show $ map constrFields $ dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf $ Foo
[[],[],[],["abc"]]
```

---

### Background

I'm creating type class that uses associated type synonyms.

```
class YesodJobQueue master where
    -- | Custom Job Type
    type JobType master
    runJob :: master -> JobType master -> IO ()

-- I have some functions that use it.
enqueue :: YesodJobQueue master => master -> JobType master -> IO ()
```

Then, I want to create API endpoints to 'enqueue' job via HTTP.
I'm creating Yesod subsite.

```
getJobR = lift $ do
    y <- getYesod  -- get YesodJobQueue instance value
    return $ magicFunction y
    -- I want to return JobType's constructors information.
    -- e.g. [{name: "Foo", argType=[]), (name: "Bar", argType: ["Int"])]
    -- I maybe ignore complex constructor.

postJobQueueR = 
    -- it receive information for create value of JobType
    -- e.g. ({"name"="Baz", args=[999]})
    enqueue y $ read x
```

If there are only nullary constructors, I can do this with `Enum` and `Bounded`.

(I'm developping [this library](https://github.com/nakaji-dayo/yesod-job-queue))

Comment: so you answered your questions?

Comment: No, I don't have answers. sorry, I'll try to fix the question.

Comment: Once you have the type, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to make WEB Form for creating value of that data type. I added the background to the question. thanks.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676) - you are trying to do with reflection something which looks like it's better suited to type classes. I suggest you review the design of [Servant](https://haskell-servant.github.io/) which is a framework for doing type-directed generation of REST APIs.

Comment: Somebody asked this on #haskell a while back, and glguy posted [this](http://lpaste.net/146259#a146262). You may find it useful or even be able to turn it into an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I guess you're right. Preblem was quite complated to me. Thanks, I'll learn more from Servant.

Comment: @DanielWagner I have solved the problem from your link. Thanks a lot! If you write it to answer, I'll accept. otherwise, I may write answer by myself.